# Двойная проверка на тег в одном OnTriggerStay2D

Tags: unity3d

Я сделал проверку два раза.
первый паз:

```
 if (other.CompareTag("StandartCircle"))
        {
            animatorr.SetBool("change", true);
            player.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 500f));
        }
```

второй раз

```
if (other.CompareTag("SecondCircle"))
        {
            player.AddForce(new Vector2(100f, 100f));
        }
```

в одном private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other), но я так понял что так нельзя делать, так как этот код не работает.[image]
Так ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так нельзя делать не потому что в `OnTriggerStay` нельзя делать несколько проверок, а потому, что это проверка по строковому литералу(по строке). А человеку свойственно ошибаться, поэтому ты можешь ввести слово с ошибкой и искать потом причину сыплющихся ошибок.
Твой код, скорее всего и не работает потому, что ты где-то сделал ошибку в строке.

Все проверки делаются по типу. Таким образом, если ты сделаешь ошибку в написании типа, то запустить игру ты не сможешь и IDE покажет где ошибка.

В твоем случае нужно не разделять круги по разным тэгам, которых может и не хватить, если типов кругов будет много, а создать общий интерфейс/класс круга, который содержит в себе нужные данные, получать этот интерфейс и уже с ним все делать.

```
public interface ICircle
{
    float SpeedMultiplier { get; }
}

public class StandartCircle : ICircle
{
    public float SpeedMultiplier { get; private set; } = 1f;
}

public class SecondCircle : ICircle
{
    public float SpeedMultiplier { get; private set; } = 1.5f;
}
```

Интерфейс `ICircle` содержит в себе свойство `SpeedMultiplier`. Классы `StandartCircle` и `SecondCircle` реализуют этот интерфейс и устанавливают свое значение множителя скорости.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpSpeed;

    private Rigidbody2D _rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent(out ICircle circle))
        {
            Jump(circle.SpeedMultiplier);
        }
    }

    private void Jump(float speedMultiplier)
    {
        var velocity = _rb.velocity;
        velocity.y = _jumpSpeed * speedMultiplier;
        _rb.velocity = velocity;
    }

}
```

Компонент `Player` содержит метод `Jump`, который, в зависимости от множителя, толкает объект вверх. В `OnTriggerEnter` получаем интерфейс через `TryGetComponent`(вернет false, если ни один из компонентов на объекте, вошедшем в триггер, не реализует этот интерфейс) и прыгаем.

Вместо интерфейса это может быть абстрактный класс, в случае, если у кругов есть какая-то общая логика, которая для всех одна и та же и никак не должна быть изменена.

Comment: Я поддерживаю вашу позицию по написанию кода, но нельзя говорить кому то просто так делать нельзя, так можно делать, просто есть стандарты и правила которые сам себе назначает либо ему назначают. Но решение полностью поддерживаю, автору вопроса рекомендация ознокомиться с данным решением вопроса

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Я сейчас показал стандарт, которому следуют все нормальные разработчики. Не я его придумал и никто мне его не назначал. Это не какой-то код стайл, который может меняться от проекта к проекту. Это - факт. Использовать строки так, как это делает он - моветон. Вместо того, чтобы сказать новичку, что можно использовать все что угодно, лучше запретить ему так делать и показать как нужно делать, чтобы он не лепил свои костыли, а потом ему здесь советовали другие костыли. Рано или поздно, к нему придет понимание того, когда что можно использовать.

Comment: Вы показали вот именно что `"стандарт, которому следуют все нормальные разработчики"`, я знаю что не вы его придумали, вы им пользуютесь, я им тоже, это наше решение, вот только в своём ответе Вы не даёте понять автору вопроса что это лишь одно из ваших решений (правил/стандартов), которому Вы следуете. Вы чётко дали человеку ответ нельзя, не дали ему возможности посмотреть на альтернативу, человек подумал и возможно до сих пор думает что поиск в OnTriggerStay не возможно реализовать более 2 поисков по тегу, хотя я думаю что это основной вопрос

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev согласен, изначально подумал, что вопрос в том, что проверки по тэгу делать не надо. Дописал свой ответ.

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev, попробуй в тестовом задании при устройстве на работу написать поиск по тегу и посмотрим насколько это `лишь одно из ваших решений`. Это не допустимо.

Comment: @Yaroslav, а это не одно из его решений которое он для себя принял, потому что оно принято в сообществе как стандарт? Я считаю что поиск по тегу не удобное решение, и его в данном случае лучше не использовать, и сказал в комментарии что автору рекомендация ознакомиться с данным подходом, но тем не менее данный поиск по тегу существует, и пока он есть и он работает в движке, о нём можно говорить, дело в том что это не лучшее решение, он не подходит для приёма на работу, не понимаю вашей агресии

Comment: Есть и можно говорить... Не путай теплое с мягким. GameObject.Find тоже есть, но о нем даже упомянать стыдно.

Answer (score -2):

Можно искать любое количество тегов, выполнение условий будет проверяться на каждом Коллайдере кто будет в нём находится, в случае `OnTriggerStay()`. Код не работает возможно из за отсутствия в нём нужных Вам тегов, попробуй выполнить отладку через:

`Debug.Log("GameObject with tag:" + other.gameObject.tag)`

И посмотреть какие теги выходят в консоле, и смотреть на состояние игры в окне Game/Scene, тогда Вы сможете понять в чём проблема, и какой тег выходит у какого обьекта